# Difference between import style

Tags: python, import

what is the difference between :

```
from file import (SomeMethod)
```

and:

```
from file import SomeMethod
```

Why ( ) are need there?

Comment: It's funny to see the rush of answers when such an obvious question is posted.

Comment: It's not terribly obvious, and Googling [python parenthesized import](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+parenthesized+import) doesn't seem to turn up anything relevant.

Comment: There are plenty of cases where the parentheses change how code is interpreted. For example, `except OSError, NameError` vs `except (OSError, NameError)`. It's not unreasonable to wonder whether the parentheses are significant here.

Comment: @user2357112 your example is why the old `except` syntax was deprecated in 3.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Indeed! Doesn't remove its relevance as an example, though.

Comment: @user2357112 it's obvious when you know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parenthesized import was described in [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) and added in Python 2.4. Briefly, <= Python 2.3 the programmer was *forced* to use the `\` for line continuation in multiline imports, that is

```
from file import SomeMethod, \
                 AnotherMethod, \
                 ThirdMethod
```

which was tiresome; it was thus decided that the parentheses be allowed for grouping as it is possible to avoid using the `\` line continuation elsewhere by just grouping expressions with parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first one to tidy your code up:

```
from file import (SomeMethod,
                  AnotherMethod,
                  ThirdMethod)
```

There might be other uses, but this is the way i've used it before.